# Can't automatically kill session on terminal close

Tags: linux, terminal, tmux

I'm using st terminal from `suckless.org`. By default there is no scrollback buffer so I would like to use `tmux` for this.

The problem is when I use a keybinding to close the terminal the `tmux` sessions stay open and they build up.

So I'm trying to automatically close session on kill-client but nothing I have tried will do it.

I've tried:

```
tmux set-hook client-detached kill-session
```

and

```
tmux set -g detach-on-destroy on
```

but neither of them work.

Comment: Do the tmux sessions at least report that they're now detached? i.e. does the terminal disappear from `tmux lsc`?

Comment: My *personal preference* is to attach to the last session automatically when I open an interactive shell (in a terminal emulator, via SSH or whatever). Only if it fails (normally because there is no session yet), I create a new session automatically. The command is `[ "$TMUX" ] || tmux a || tmux`. This way sessions never build up unless I explicitly make them. Instead of opening new terminal emulator windows I create windows and/or panes in tmux. I'm not saying your way (desired way) is wrong; but maybe you haven't considered this other way and if you do then *maybe* you will find it better.